# How can I loop my array to total the score percentage based on his correct answer?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have this response

```
[0] => Array (
    [name] => Test
    [question_id] => 4
    [question_choice_id] => 14
    [choice_level] => 0
    )
[1] => Array (
    [name] => Test
    [question_id] => 5
    [question_choice_id] => 19
    [choice_level] => 0
    )
[2] => Array (
    [name] => Test
    [question_id] => 6
    [question_choice_id] => 24
    [choice_level] => 0
    )
[3] => Array (
    [name] => Test
    [question_id] => 7
    [question_choice_id] => 26
    [choice_level] => 0
    )
[4] => Array (
    [name] => Test
    [question_id] => 8
    [question_choice_id] => 29
    [choice_level] => 1
    )
[5] => Array (
    [name] => Test
    [question_id] => 9
    [question_choice_id] => 36
    [choice_level] => 0
    )
[6] => Array (
    [name] => Test
    [question_id] => 1
    [question_choice_id] => 2
    [choice_level] => 0
    )
[7] => Array (
    [name] => Test
    [question_id] => 2
    [question_choice_id] => 7
    [choice_level] => 0
    )
[8] => Array (
    [name] => Test
    [question_id] => 3
    [question_choice_id] => 9
    [choice_level] => 0
    )
```

I want to get the percentage of the user with the formula of

`Score = the_right_answer / total_count_array * 100`

The correct answer has a value of 1 in the `choice_level` columns

so for my example is, the formula should be

`Score = 1/ 9 * 100`

How can I get the total from this array?

Once I get the answer I just like to return them to my view.

```
  public function progress(){

    $category_id = Session::get('category_id');
    $user_set_id = Session::get('user_set_id');

    $score = Answer::get_user_score($user_set_id,$category_id);

      return view('pages.user.user_progress', [
        'name' => '',
        'score' => '',
      ]);

  }
```

Can anyone help me on how to do this properly? any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: That's an odd way to calculate score percentage, should it be `right_answer / count_of_array * 100`?

Comment: @catcon oh sorry sir, i already updated  my question, thank you for the correction sir, I had been confused sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on `Score = total count_of_array / the_right_answer * 100`:

1. for `total count_of_array` could be calculated easily using `count($answes)`
2. for calculating `the_right_answer`, you can use `array_map()` or manual loop:

   ```
    $total = count($answers);
    $correct = 0;
    foreach($answers as $answer){
      if($answer['choice_level'] == '1'){
        $correct++;
      }
    }
   ```

   the snippet above will give you `$correct` as total correct answer
3. Now that you have the needed data, you can then do the calculation yourself. However, I would remind you that when the user doesn't have any correct answer, you will face a `Division by zero` warning. Keep that in mind

Comment: yes sir, thank you sir, my formula is incorrect, it should be ```the_right_answer/total_count_array * 100. thank you very much sir.

Comment: @ariefbayu can you help me to solve this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64426527/skip-key-and-its-value-if-key-is-empty-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

```
for each($arrayname['score'] as $item){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since apparently `choice_level` can only take the values `0` or `1` you can use [`array_sum`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) to get the number of correct answers. You will need to reduce the response array to just that field first, you can achive that with [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php). So all together:

```
$score = array_sum(array_column($answers, 'choice_level')) / count($answers) * 100;
```